# How to Invoke an executable with Powershell, but not wait for it to finish?

Tags: powershell

I need to run a C executable, which takes about 20 seconds to run, from a Powershell script. I do this as follows:

```
Invoke-Expression ".\test_vibration.exe"
# Do stuff
```

While this is running, I want to continue with the rest of my script, as there are certain actions I need to perform while the executable is running. Currently, the script waits for the command to finish before continuing. How can I avoid this?

Comment: `Start-Process .\test_vibration.exe`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yeah, this works. Thank you!